# Why is my string not showing after transfer via SHM?

Tags: c, shared-memory

I've created the following types to transfer a list of nodes from one process to the other one:

```
typedef struct {
  char *from;
  char *to;
} Edge;

typedef struct {
  size_t numEdges;
  Edge *fst;
} EdgeList;

typedef struct {
  EdgeList buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
  ...
} CircularBuffer; /**< used as shared memory. */
```

This is what the process that sends the `EdgeList` looks like:

```
  // open shared memory -> shm_open()
  int shm_fd = shm_open(SHM_PATH, O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
  ...

  // map shared memory into memory -> mmap()
  CircularBuffer *shm = mmap(NULL, sizeof(CircularBuffer),
                             PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
  ...

  while (true) {
    shm->buffer[...] = getSolution(...);
    ...
  }

  ...
```

This is what the process that receives the `EdgeList` looks like:

```
  // create shared memory -> shm_open()
  int shm_fd = shm_open(SHM_PATH, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
  ...

  // set shared memory size -> ftruncate()
  ftruncate(shm_fd, sizeof(CircularBuffer);
  ...

  // map shared memory into memory -> mmap()
  CircularBuffer *shm = mmap(NULL, sizeof(CircularBuffer),
                             PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
  ...

  EdgeList bestSolution = {.numEdges = SIZE_MAX, .fst = NULL};
  while (true) {
    EdgeList solution = shm->buffer[...];
    if (solution.numEdges < bestSolution.numEdges) {
      bestSolution = solution;
      // I can read 'bestSolution.numEdges' here just fine.
      // But i can't read 'bestSolution.fst[i].from' and 'bestSolution.fst[i].to' for some reason.
    }
    ...
}
...
```

Now here is where things behave unexpectedly: The receiving process is not showing me any strings from the shared memory but everything else works just as expected.

I have access to `bestSolution.numEdges` after it being read from the shared memory, but not to `bestSolution.fst[i].from` and `bestSolution.fst[i].to` (with `i` being a legal index from that array).

When I try to read these strings, I only see `(null)` instead of the strings. Can I fix this issue?

Comment: Data race.  You can't just read and write shared memory as normal variables; the C memory model says the compiler is entitled to assume there is no concurrent access to normal variables, and it optimizes accordingly.  You need synchronization: mutexes are the simplest, lock-free `_Atomic`s are more advanced and harder to get right.

Comment: I see @NateEldrege - I get this error even with a single worker process and I use multiple semaphores to ensure mutual exclusion in the critical reading / writing area.

Comment: Then, I think you need to provide a [mcve].  The bug is very likely in one of the `...` regions you left out.